# Is there any book / tutorial where i can get the summary of all engineering math stuff

Tags: reference-request, computer-science

I studied math with all topics but that was 10 years back and now i have forgot them. Now i need to dive into statistics field and machine learning stuff. Now i don't have time for study different books on diff topics.

I just want to brush up all the topics like matrices , algebra, vectors , probablility , sets , functions , limits etc.

is there any single book / pdf which can just revise my whole math rather digging deep into every topic

juts like we can reference or nutshell type books

Comment: For statistics, you need to be strong on most of the areas you mentioned, a quick read will not do. Statistics is difficult for most to understand well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Greenberg is very useful according to one of my applied math professors with whom I took vector calculus (we used Greenberg's book). Although he is not an engineer he used it throughout grad school. Mind you, it is pretty thick but it has everything -- linear algebra, differential equations, calculus, etc. If you prefer watching someone explain I would recommend Chris Tisdell's YouTube [channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/DrChrisTisdell).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is a really hard task...

Best i can think of is maybe : [http://www.amazon.com/Cracking-Mathematics-Subject-Graduate-Preparation/dp/0375429727](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375429727)

Some of the problems are also very difficult in a way thats specifc only towards the gre examination as far as ive found.

Comment: I do not think this is at all what the OP is looking for. Reviewing material such as vectors, algebra, matrices, etc. is a far removed subset of the advanced mathematics that the gre math subject test is designed to test. There is only one reason to take this test, and that is to get into a math graduate degree program in the US.

Comment: @mixedmath I suggested the specific book because it contains a review of all of the topics he cited and goes into a moderately global discussion of each individual topic. I did not say to take the gre test, but to merely use this one specific book as a reference, because it is quite decent(I find myself constantly using it as a reference in math grad school).